# Remove and Replace Special Characters from Columns

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following table

```
Table - City

City         Country      Comments
Chicago       USA         Winter Weather: Cold %,  Summer *Weather - hot\warm
Dallas        USA         Winter Weather: Not so Cold $,  Summer Weather - hot\warm
```

I am selecting the columns (select City, Country, Comments from City ) but I want to remove/replace characters from comment field like

```
: (replace with -)
\ (Replace with /)
$ (replace with S)
(2 spaces - replace with 1 space)
(Trim all columns - data cannot end with a space)
% (Remove Character)
* (Remove Character)
```

The query output should be like -

```
City         Country      Comments
Chicago       USA         Winter Weather- Cold , Summer Weather - hot/warm
Dallas        USA         Winter Weather- Not so Cold S, Summer Weather - hot/warm
```

How can I achieve this using spark SQL?

Comment: [regexp_replace](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/index.html#regexp_replace), but it will take multiple passes unless you write a udf.

Comment: Any idea how to write it in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `translate` and 'regexp_replace` like below:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = Seq(
            ("Chicago"    ,   "USA",        " Winter Weather: Cold %,  Summer *Weather - hot\\warm")
           ,("Dallas"      ,  "USA" ,       " Winter Weather: Not so Cold $,  Summer Weather - hot\\warm")
           ).toDF("City",         "Country"     , "Comments")
        
df.show(truncate=false)

df.withColumn("commentsMod", regexp_replace(translate(col("Comments"), ":\\$%*", "-/S"), "\\s{2}", " ")).show(false)

+-------+-------+----------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
|City   |Country|Comments                                                  |commentsMod                                              |
+-------+-------+----------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
|Chicago|USA    | Winter Weather: Cold %,  Summer *Weather - hot\warm      | Winter Weather- Cold , Summer Weather - hot/warm        |
|Dallas |USA    | Winter Weather: Not so Cold $,  Summer Weather - hot\warm| Winter Weather- Not so Cold S, Summer Weather - hot/warm|
+-------+-------+----------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

NOTE: spark-version is 3.2.1